# Prompt only once for username and password for svn export in makefile

Tags: svn, makefile, passwords

I want to write a `Makefile` to export several files from an `svn` repository, but to prompt for username and password only **once**. The files are located in different directories in the same repository. I'm using `svn+ssh`.

Answer (score 1):

SVN client will prompt you for the password only once and will then cache it by default. The next time you attempt to access the repository that's using the same authentication realm the cached password will be reused and you will not get an authentication prompt. Read [SVNBook | Client Credentials](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.netmodel.html#svn.serverconfig.netmodel.creds).

Comment: That's not the behavior I observe. I think it may be ssh prompting me, since I'm using svn+ssh.

Comment: Since you are using svn+ssh protocol to access the repository, you may be using ssh keys to authenticate. If your ssh key is configured with a passphrase, you may need to create an ssh-agent to hold the passpharse and use `ssh-add` to store the passphrase in the agent, so the passphrase will not be prompted again in the same terminal/console session.